# Assembly Programming Illegal indexing mode

Tags: assembly, tasm

I want to know why this program gives me an error.

Turbo Assembler Version 3.0 Copyright (c) 1988, 1991 Borland International

Assembling file: sample.asm
**Error** sample.asm(16) Illegal indexing mode
Error messages: 1
Warning message: none
Passes: 1
Remaining memory: 470k

```
 title test.program
cstack segment para stack 'stack'
dw 200h
cstack ends

cdata segment para 'data'
msg1 db 'Sample progr! $'
cdata ends

ccode segment para 'code'
 assume cs: ccode, ds: cdata ,ss: cstack
main:
 mov cl,00
stri:
 mov ah,02h
 mov dl,[msg1 +cl] ;< this line give me an error of illegal indexing mode 
 int 21h

 add cl,02
 cmp dl,12
 jbe stri

 mov ah,4ch
 int 21h

ccode ends
end main
```

Comment: The appropriate action to take would be to look at what you've got at line 16 and cross-check that against Intel's software developer's manual. Hint: it's complaining about your use of `cl` in `[msg1 + cl]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a register to loop through the characters of *msg1* then use an indexing register like SI, DI, or BX.

When you `add cl,2` you will not correctly display the string!

Comparing with 12 will not include the exclamation mark character.

```
main:
mov si,00
stri:
mov ah,02h
mov dl,[msg1 + si] ;< this line give me an error of illegal indexing mode 
int 21h
add si,1
cmp si,13
jbe stri
```

Comment: Note that he is comparing the character to 12, not the counter. As there is no such character in the string, the code will continue looping until it finds a 12 somewhere in memory.

Comment: i expect that the output is SML RG! but when i run the output is something like >i